# How does std::stack enforce that the container class meets certain requirements

Tags: c++, stack, std

If you create a `stack` with a container that doesn't meet the requirements of the required underlying container, you get a compile error. How is this an error that can be determined at compile-time vs. run-time.

For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>

using namespace std;

class Test {
    int data;
};

int main()
{
    stack<int, Test> s;
    // s.push(5);
    cout<<"Hello World";

    return 0;
}
```

Will return the compile errors:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/stack:61:0,
                 from main.cpp:10:
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_stack.h: In instantiation of ‘class std::stack<int, Test>’:
<span class="error_line" onclick="ide.gotoLine('main.cpp',20)">main.cpp:20:22</span>:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_stack.h:102:46: error: no type named ‘value_type’ in ‘class Test’
       typedef typename _Sequence::value_type _Sequence_value_type;
                                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_stack.h:124:61: error: no type named ‘value_type’ in ‘class Test’
       typedef typename _Sequence::value_type                value_type;
                                                             ^~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_stack.h:125:61: error: no type named ‘reference’ in ‘class Test’
       typedef typename _Sequence::reference                 reference;
                                                             ^~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_stack.h:126:61: error: no type named ‘const_reference’ in ‘class Test’
       typedef typename _Sequence::const_reference           const_reference;
                                                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_stack.h:127:61: error: no type named ‘size_type’ in ‘class Test’
       typedef typename _Sequence::size_type                 size_type;
                                                             ^~~~~~~~~
```

I wanted to be able to enforce requirements for a template type and I was hoping to use how `std::stack` does it as a reference.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux good call on the `stl` vs `std`. Just corrected it.

Comment: Note that there are ways to check various things regarding template type (C++20 concepts, SFINAE, `static_assert` with `<type_traits>` library, ...), but sometimes you can just go with "I assume type `T` will have these members available for me" and let the compiler detect any issues.

Comment: "I wanted to be able to enforce requirements for a template type" -- it sounds like that may be your Real Question.  If so, see the comment above this one.

Comment: @DrewDormann thanks for clearing that up. Didn't want to merge two questions into one post, but that was my main intent of trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::stack` isn't actually doing anything.  Inside `std::stack`, there is a like like

```
using value_type = Container::value_type;
```

and for your case, `Container` is `Test` and since `Test::value_type` does not exist, you get a compiler error.

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick reply! I'll accept once the time limit is up